# how to make two If condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement

Two conditions I want to apply for a button that will show the application when applied and if the user has a login then the button will show and ask to login.

**Blade**

```
            @if (Auth::check())
            @if ($tuitionJob->checkApply())

            <form action="{{url('/tuition/apply')}}" method="POST">
              @csrf
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$tuitionJob->id}}" name="tuitionid">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary login-apply-btn my-2 text-light pull-right">
                  Apply <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
                @else
              <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary login-apply-btn my-2 text-light pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
                Login For Apply
              </a>
            @else
              <a href="tuition/job" class="btn btn-primary login-apply-btn my-2 text-light pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
                 Applied
              </a>

            @endif
            @endif
```

**Model**

```
public function checkApply(){
  return \DB::table('tuition_applies')->where('users_id', auth()->user()->id)
  ->where('tuition_post_id', $this->id)->exists();
}
```

Comment: Try switching the if statements to look like this:
if ($tuitionJob->checkApply())
if (Auth::check())

Answer (score 0):

Try && Logical Operator

```
   @if(Auth::check() && $tuitionJob->checkApply())
     //Code
   @else
     //Code
   @endif
```

May be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
            @if (Auth::check())
            @if ($tuitionJob->checkApply())

            <form action="{{url('/tuition/apply')}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
              <input type="hidden" value="{{$tuitionJob->id}}" name="tuitionid">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary login-apply-btn my-2 text-light pull-right">
               Apply <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
              </button>
            </form>
            @else
            <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary login-apply-btn my-2 text-light pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
            Login For Apply
            </a>
            @endif
            @else
            <a href="tuition/job" class="btn btn-primary login-apply-btn my-2 text-light pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
             Applied
            </a>
        @endif
```

Try this